# Updating new version for unpublished app in google playstore and publish when new version is live

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My First version 1.0 has bugs, so i have unpublished the app in google play store. Now i want to upload new version 2.0 and want 2.0 to be visible for the users only after it becomes live. Till then status of app will be unpublished.

My Question is

1. since the app status is unpublished, Will google play console approve the new version(2.0) app or they reject it ??
2. If they approve new updated version 2.0 and it is live and after that if i publish the app (Where Version 2.0 is live in play store), is version 2.0 is visible to users or version 1.0 ? (Am asking this about new users. i know Old users will be having 1.0 until they update the app)
3. Or is it better to upload new version (2.0) with new package name by creating a new application

Please suggest me.

Comment: Stack Overflow cannot answer what Google Play reviewers will or will not do, as that is a policy question. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the 2.0 apk and republish the app that's it.

Google will review your new apk and publish the 2.0 apk for all.

Users who installed 1.0 will get an update to 2.0.